# How to set specific corner and shadow to UIView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, layer

I am trying to set top left and top right corners to tab bar along with shadow.

I am using below function which is in my UIView extension:

```
func addShadowWithCurve(usingCorners corners : UIRectCorner,cornerRadii : CGSize, shadowColor:UIColor,shadowOpacity:Float,shadowRadius:CGFloat,shadowOffset:CGSize){
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: cornerRadii)
    layer.masksToBounds = false
  
    let frameLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    frameLayer.path = path.cgPath
    frameLayer.shadowPath = path.cgPath

    frameLayer.lineWidth = 1
    frameLayer.strokeColor = RRSTokens.colorGrey10.cgColor
    frameLayer.fillColor = backgroundColor?.cgColor
    frameLayer.shadowOffset = shadowOffset
    frameLayer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
    frameLayer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
    frameLayer.shadowColor = shadowColor.cgColor

    layer.mask = frameLayer
    layer.insertSublayer(frameLayer, at: 0)
}
```

But the result is not expected, there is a black border line visible at the top of tab bar. I have tried multiple attempts to play around layer properties to remove that black line but no luck. This is what it looks like:

[image: Black line visible at top of tab bar]

Comment: Can you show the code for the view that you are applying this function to? For example `rectangleView.addShadowWithCurve(...`

Comment: self.tabBar.addShadowWithCurve(usingCorners: [.topLeft,.topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20), shadowColor: UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.15), shadowOpacity: 1, shadowRadius: 6, shadowOffset: CGSize(width: 0, height: -2))

Comment: Works fine for me: [screenshot](https://github.com/aheze/DeveloperAssets/blob/master/Screen%20Shot%202021-03-04%20at%2011.16.26%20AM.png?raw=true). You probably set the `borderWidth` and `borderColor` of `tabBar` somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for checking, can we remove yellow colour which is around curves to view background colour?

Comment: Sure. See [here](https://gist.github.com/aheze/285aad93407bd3d0e72bb73e3c45b2d7). Just set `tabBar.backgroundColor` to clear + set `frameLayer.fillColor` to the desired color, like `.white`.

Comment: Thank You @aheze

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfect just add below line to your code:

```
self.tabBar.barStyle = .blackOpaque
```

Hope it'll solve your problem. Thank you.